# How come I can't get $\int f(t)$ from performing derivative/anti-derivative operation on $\int f(t)$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know the the area under the curve of some function between the coordinates $t_0$ and $t_1$, is:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(t) \space dt=\frac{\left(t_0^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_1^2}$$
How do I find $f(t)$?

I couldn't get this to work with multiple variables, so I added a constraint - which is very workable - to fix one of the values, let's say $t_1$, as a constant, and allow the other parameter, say $t_0$, vary as $t$. So I got:
$$\int_{t}^{t_1} f(t) \space dt=\frac{\left(t^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_1^2}$$
Now I can take the derivative:
$$f(t)=t\frac{\left(t^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_1^2}$$
So how come I can't integrate this and get the original formula?
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} t\frac{\left(t^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_1^2}\space dt=-\frac{t_0^4+2t_0^2t_1^2-3t_1^4}{4t_1^2}$$What is the right answer and, if possible, what am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
f[t_, t1_] = (t^2 + t1^2)^2/(4*t1^4)
D[f[t, t1], t]
FullSimplify[Integrate[%, {t, t0, t1}]]
```

Here's a plot I did just to validate that the result wasn't the same:

```
t1 = 9.653442*10^17; 
Plot\[{(t0^2 + t1^2)^2/(4*t1^4), (t0^4 + 2*t0^2*t1^2 - 3*t1^4)/(4*
     t1^4)}, {t0, 0, t1}\]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Note that when the upper and lower limits are equal, the integral must evaluate to zero.  Could there be a typo in the formula?  Also, when the limits are exchanged ...

Comment: @LouisB - There's no typo. What I know for sure is the area under the curve between $t_0$ and $t_1$ is:$$\frac{\left(t_0^2+t_1^2\right)^2}{4t_1^2}$$ I am less sure of the other features, such as whether this function has a derivative.

Comment: Since `0=f[t0,t0]=t0^2`, it means that `t0==0`. So `f[t]==D[t^2/4,t]==t/2`.

Comment: Find $f(t_1)$ by differentiating the result with respect to $t_1$, according to the fundamental theorem of calculus. Then replace $t_1$ by $t$ if you like. However, I agree with @LouisB. And @ cvgmt derives a necessary conclusion if there's no typo and $t_0$ is not a free variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
f = (t0^2 + t1^2)^2/(4 t1^2) DiracDelta[t - (t0 + t1)/2];

Integrate[f, {t, t0, t1}, Assumptions -> t0 < t1]

(*  (t0^2 + t1^2)^2/(4 t1^2)  *)
```

Comment: Holy crap! That works!  Looks like I need to do some reading on DiracDelta.

Comment: Nicely played...